# static build of Qt with built-in MySQL library

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I am trying to deploy single-file application using MySQL connection with Qt. And I discovered that app still depends on `libmysql.dll`. That is because even though qt mysql driver plugin is static, it links to dynamic version of library. I tried configuring Qt with both `-qt-sql-mysql` and `-plugin-sql-mysql`,

Now here's the question: how can I build Qt so mysql library would be built in static qt mysql driver plugin? (or, directly into `QtSql`)

Answer (score 1):

Use/build a static version of libmysql (put the *.lib file in Qt's lib folder).

Configure with -qt-sql-mysql is enough.

Make sure that the lib is build with the same compiler/linker.

Comment: I've tried building with static version of libmysql, but it still (for some reason) required dynamic library.

Comment: What compiler/OS are you using?

Comment: When you build MySQL or MariaDB client, you have two libs (*.a extension), a dynamic and a static one. Rename the static one to libmysql.a and make sure that is the only one the linker finds.